# How to draw shapes in JavaFX when scale of group containing Shape is not default

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I am learning about creating shapes when mouse is dragged in JavaFX and I can create the shapes when mouse is dragged but a problem shows up when I change the `scaleX` and `scaleY` of the `Group` containing that shape. The problem is that when I try to create a shape when scale is not 1 then the position of shape changes event when I wrote in code to set it's translate value according to mouse location. I've tried to solve this problem many times but I can't figure out why is this happening or how to resolve this problem.

Here is My code:

I am using code to modify `Rectangle` called `object` when mouse is dragged but it's position is shifting when I drag mouse keeping the scale other than 1.Again for clarification I am trying to create rectangle when mouse is dragged. but it's positions is not where the mouse is i.e. the position is shifted when scale of group is not 1.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application{
    
    private Group  group;
    private double mousePointX;
    private double mousePointY;
    
    public static void main(String... arguments){ launch(arguments); }
    
    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        
        group = new Group();
        
        Pane pane = new Pane(group);
        pane.setOnMousePressed(this::recordPosition);
        pane.setOnMouseDragged(this::makeShape);
        pane.setOnScroll(this::handleScroll);
        
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(pane)));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    //record mouse position
    private void recordPosition(MouseEvent event){
        mousePointX = event.getX();
        mousePointY = event.getY();
    }
    
    //method to make shape
    private void makeShape(MouseEvent event){
        Rectangle object;
        object = new Rectangle(200, 200, Color.BLUE);
        object.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    
        group.getChildren().addAll(object);
        
        object.setTranslateX(mousePointX - group.getTranslateX());
        object.setTranslateY(mousePointY - group.getTranslateY());
        object.setHeight(event.getY() - mousePointY);
        object.setWidth(event.getX() - mousePointX);
    }
    
    //method to control scroll
    private void handleScroll(ScrollEvent event){
        if(event.isControlDown()){
            zoom(Math.pow(1.01, event.getDeltaY()), event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
        }else{
            group.setTranslateX(this.group.getTranslateX() + event.getDeltaX());
            group.setTranslateY(this.group.getTranslateY() + event.getDeltaY());
        }
        event.consume();
    }
    
    //method to control zoom
    private void zoom(double factor, double x, double y){
        double oldScale = group.getScaleX();
        double scale    = oldScale * factor;
        
        if(scale < 0.05) scale = 0.05;
        if(scale > 50) scale = 50;
        
        group.setScaleX(scale);
        group.setScaleY(scale);
        
        double f      = (scale / oldScale) - 1;
        Bounds bounds = this.group.localToScene(this.group.getBoundsInLocal());
        double dx     = (x - (bounds.getWidth() / 2 + bounds.getMinX()));
        double dy     = (y - (bounds.getHeight() / 2 + bounds.getMinY()));
        
        group.setTranslateX(this.group.getTranslateX() - f * dx);
        group.setTranslateY(this.group.getTranslateY() - f * dy);
    }
    
}
```

So, What is the correct way to draw a Shape when Scale of the group containing that shape is not 1??

Please Suggest me.

Comment: Please clarify what are you trying to achieve ? Do you want the rectangle to respond to scroll after drag is finished ? Or while mouse is dragged ?  What is the expected result ? What is the actual result ? Is the problem with scroll or with scroll + <cntrl> down ?  Add the needed information to the question, not as comments.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how my questions were answered: " Do you want the rectangle to respond to scroll after drag is finished ? Or while mouse is dragged ? What is the expected result ? What is the actual result ? Is the problem with scroll or with scroll + <cntrl> down ?"  ( `handleScroll` is invoked only when you scroll. Not when you drag).

Comment: "I have no problem with handleScroll" how do you know ? when you "run the code and change scale using (ctrl+mouse wheel)" you invoke `handleScroll` which modifies group scale and transition. If there is no problem with `handleScroll` remove it and hard code a certain scale for testing. This will make you code Mcve.

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest way but still a way, the problem is that is very hard to calculate how Scale impact on your group(if somebody knows how to it will be wonderful), so I went around it:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MySolution extends Application{

    List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    private Group  group;
    private Rectangle object ;
    private Pane pane;
    private double mousePointX;
    private double mousePointY;

    public static void main(String... arguments){ launch(arguments); }

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage){

        group = new Group();

        pane = new Pane(group);
        pane.setOnMousePressed(this::recordPosition);
        pane.setOnMouseDragged(this::makeShape);
        pane.setOnScroll(this::handleScroll);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(pane)));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    //record mouse position
    private void recordPosition(MouseEvent event){
        mousePointX = event.getX();
        mousePointY = event.getY();
        object = new Rectangle(0, 0, Color.BLUE);
        object.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        group.getChildren().addAll(object);
    }

    //method to make shape
    private void makeShape(MouseEvent event){
        if(object!=null){
            object.setTranslateX(mousePointX - group.getTranslateX());
            object.setTranslateY(mousePointY - group.getTranslateY());
            object.setHeight(event.getY() - mousePointY);
            object.setWidth(event.getX() - mousePointX);
        }
    }

    //method to control scroll
    private void handleScroll(ScrollEvent event){
        if(event.isControlDown()){
            zoom(Math.pow(1.01, event.getDeltaY()), event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
        }else{
            group.setTranslateX(this.group.getTranslateX() + event.getDeltaX());
            group.setTranslateY(this.group.getTranslateY() + event.getDeltaY());
            for (Group g:groups) {
                g.setTranslateX(g.getTranslateX() + event.getDeltaX());
                g.setTranslateY(g.getTranslateY() + event.getDeltaY());
            }
        }
        event.consume();
    }

    //method to control zoom
    private void zoom(double factor, double x, double y){
        groups.add(group);
        for (Group g:groups) {
            double oldScale = g.getScaleX();
            double scale    = oldScale * factor;
            if(scale < 0.05) scale = 0.05;
            if(scale > 50) scale = 50;
            g.setScaleX(scale);
            g.setScaleY(scale);
            double f      = (scale / oldScale) - 1;
            Bounds bounds = g.localToScene(g.getBoundsInLocal());
            double dx     = (x - (bounds.getWidth() / 2 + bounds.getMinX()));
            double dy     = (y - (bounds.getHeight() / 2 + bounds.getMinY()));
            g.setTranslateX(g.getTranslateX() - f * dx);
            g.setTranslateY(g.getTranslateY() - f * dy);
        }
        group = new Group();
        pane.getChildren().add(group);
    }

}
```

Comment: There's problem in this. when trying to create rectangle and keeping mouse dragging and making it smaller and bigger it glitches. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brAJi.png). but thank you because I guess this may lead to  a better way.

Comment: I not sure I got the problem (that isn't in the first code) but I edited my code so you can get it smaller, did it solve it?